# Identify items in each grid using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-analysis

I have data set in `refxy` size `500 x 3` where each row represents one location such that 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns have `x` coordinate, `y` coordinate and the `weight v1` of the location. Using following code, I divide this area into `14 x 18` grid and I find how many points in each grid which gives in output `blockNums_v1`.

```
function gridcounttest
load refxy

x = refxy(:,1);
y = refxy(:,2);
v1 = refxy(:,3);

 nBinsX = 14 ;
 nBinsY = 18 ;
 xg     = linspace( 0, 700, nBinsX+1 ) ;
 yg     = linspace( 0, 900, nBinsY+1 ) ;
 nCells = nBinsX * nBinsY ;

 xId = sum( bsxfun( @ge, x, xg(1:end-1) ), 2 ) ;
 yId = sum( bsxfun( @ge, y, yg(1:end-1) ), 2 ) ;
 cellId = nBinsY * (xId - 1) + yId ;

 blockNums_v1  = accumarray( cellId, 1, [nCells, 1] ) 
 blockSum_v1  = accumarray( cellId, v1, [nCells, 1] ) 
 blockMean_v2 = accumarray( cellId, v1, [nCells, 1], @mean )
```

Can someone please help me to identify which points, probably the row numbers, are included in each grid? e.g., if grid number 10 has 3 points which are in row 23, 51 and 432. This code gives output 3 but NOT 23, 51, 432 which I need to get now :)

Thanks !!!

Comment: What is `ge` and what does the data `refxy` look like?

Comment: @RobertStettler `ge`is greater than or equal to. http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the rows of points which are in a grid element by

```
rowsOfValuesInGridpoint10 = find(cellId == 10);
```

The problem is that the output is not uniform, when you want to find the points of several grid elements.

You could store the rows in Matlab-cells, e.g.

```
for i=1:nCells
 rowsInThisElement{i} = find(cellId == i);
end
rowsInThisElement{10}
```